# Port forwarding an ssh request from a global IP to a specific local IP

Tags: linux, ssh, networking, iptables, port-forwarding

I need to accomplish port forwarding from a global IP address to a specific local IP address on a local system running on Linux that is connected to the Internet via a Squid Proxy Server Running over Linux.

The Squid Proxy Server has a global IP address, and, Internet connections are routed through it to the almost all local systems that have static local IP addresses. The Global IP address is in the `210.*.*.*` range, and, the local IP addresses are in the range of `192.168.*.*`

How do I accomplish this.

Comment: Without more details, this is a request for a manual, not a specific question.  Note that the information provided is not sufficient for anyone to give you a straight answer.  It mainly misses your current routing and firewall rules.  When you say that the "Internet connections are routed through it", do you mean that some ports are already forwarded to local machines (IPs)?  If it is, you should simply copy one of those rules and simply change the port and local IP.

Comment: You can use SNAT one Global IP to One Local IP.

Comment: Apologies, my intention was to keep the question short and simple, I did not expect the manual.
There are no specific routing and firewall rules as far as I know except for  entries in the /etc/host.allow file to allow only certain IP addresses to ssh to the Squid server remotely.
I need to one local system to be accessed by a remote system with a global IP which is part of our organization and sits at another geographic location, the local system sits behind a Squid Proxy Server. I need to set up ssh access to the local system, so that it can be accessed from the remote system directly.

Comment: If you want to be able to reach both machines with `ssh`, then you'll need to use different ports.

Comment: here's your answer -  http://serverfault.com/questions/140622/how-can-i-port-forward-with-iptables

Comment: @Julie Pelletier, right now I need to reach the local system from the remote system only.
Remote system > server with global IP > system with local IP, I hope I am clear.

Comment: @I got it now you get it.Did you pay someone to answer it here? And You can expect very clear answer.Even You didnt know how to do it.You said you didnt need manual.Better you learned networking concept properly.

Comment: @supraidy, no I did not pay anyone to answer it here, yes I do not know how to do it, yes I still do not need a manual, it is easily available in many places. 

I will learn networking concepts, but that will take time, hence I am looking for help here, I need a solution, not taunts and junk, you are welcome to help too.

Avoid getting personal, and, irritated, this is not the place for displaying these immature traits.

Comment: When you knew you can use Static NAT to solve the problem.Many iptables tutorial on internet.You can find it.I didnt know you didnt know how to search iptables using Static NAT.

Comment: They answered  SNAT to you.Did you think the answer was junk from me?

Comment: @supriady , the answer from you was not junk, but saying that others were paid to answer this question is definitely junk, it is highly disrespectful to all, and, everyone who try and help on this forum, we all know something, and, do not know a lot, so taunts too are unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way is to rely exclusively on NATing:

Forward all packets reaching the $PUBLICIP on port 2222 to $LOCALIP on port 22:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d $PUBLICIP/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination $LOCALIP:22
```

Route the traffic coming from $LOCALIP on the $PUBLICIP's interface:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s $LOCALIP/32 -j SNAT --to-source $PUBLICIP
```

Then you can simply `ssh -p 2222 $PUBLICIP` from your local system.

Comment: This would mean that any incoming ssh request would be forwarded to the particular local IP, is it not.

Comment: Routing and filtering are not done at the application level so you don't care if it's ssh, you simply look at the IP and port.  So accessing your public IP on port 2222 would access the VPN machine on port 22.